# Converting SIMD2 Position and Marking in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

In trying to learn more about ARKit, I have been exploring the `ARBodyTrackingConfiguration` available in `ARKit 3.0` in iOS 13. Ideally, I would like to receive a particular "joint" that is tracked in my session, then mark this point on the screen with a indicator (a dot, a UIView, etc).  I am receiving locations based on the following code;

```
if let body = frame.detectedBody {
    let skeleton = body.skeleton
    let rightHand = skeleton.landmark(for: .rightHand)
    print("HAND:", rightHand)
}
```

If a person is detected in the frame, I receive the output like so:

```
HAND: SIMD2<Float>(0.6045535, 0.63141185)
```

**My question is two-fold**:

How do I convert this point to a X, Y location that correlates to my app, and how could I "mark" this location with something simple (like a small, square, UIView).  Not being overly familiar with `RealityKit` or `SceneKit`, I'm not sure how to draw a simple box like I would in UIKit.